# Any body have any luck with ShellTileSchedule?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification

Any body have any luck with ShellTileSchedule? I have followed the Microsoft example and still have gotten no where.

["How to: Update Your Tile Without Push Notifications for Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Has any one seen a complete example that works on a device or emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes...I started with the sample at http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingPushNotificationsLab/Exercise-2-Introduction-to-the-Toast-and-Tile-Notifications-for-Alerts/

and skipped immediately down to "Task 3 – Processing Scheduled Tile Notifications on the Phone."  After that I had to wait about 1 hour, leaving the emulator running on my desktop (1 hour is the minimum update interval, indicated as such for "performance considerations."

```
            _shellTileSchedule = new ShellTileSchedule
                                 {
                                     Recurrence = UpdateRecurrence.Interval,
                                     Interval = UpdateInterval.EveryHour,
                                     StartTime = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59),
                                     RemoteImageUri = new Uri(@"http://cdn3.afterdawn.fi/news/small/windows-phone-7-series.png")
                                 };
```

Note that setting the StartTime to DateTime.Now - 59 minutes did nothing.  It still waited a full hour for its first update.  I could not find any mechanism to perform "go to this URI and Update yourself NOW!", other than calling out to a web service that tickles a Tile Notification.

Comment: I let it run all day and I am seeing it updated finally. Understanding that you saw it work after waiting an hour helped allot. It turned out I was not binding to the channel properly was the main hangup.

Answer (score 1):

as @avidgator said, you'll have to wait an hour.

i have written a tutorial on how to update the tile instantly here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/04/03/windows-phone-7-live-tile-schedules-ndash-executing-instant-live-tile-updates

basically it involves opening a push/toast update channel and then getting the phone to send "itself" a live tile update request. this will trigger the phone to go and get the tile "right now"

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Are the channels necessary for this kind of update?
Is there a full code example of what has to be done to create an app that just updates its tile?
BTW: How about setting the Recurrence to UpdateRecurrence.Onetime and the StartTime to Now + 20 seconds for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I just got an tile update after an hour without channels and so on. So that answered my first question. But having to wait an hour while trying to develop an app is... unsatisfying.

Comment: Be careful if you have registered the channel previously it still works.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Just use the following code when you setup ShellTileSchedule.

```
ShellTile applicationTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
applicationTile.Update(
     new StandardTileData { 
           BackgroundImage = new Uri("www.ash.com/logo.jpg"), 
           Title = "" 
     });
```